# How can I set up an alert for the creation of a new container in an Azure Storage Account?

Tags: azure, alert, azure-monitor

I need to create an alert that sends an email every time a new container is created in a specific Azure storage account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have any built signals to create a Azure monitor alert to monitor the container creation in the storage account.

To accomplish this, you'll need to use Azure Monitor and write a kusto query to monitor and send an email every time a new container is created in the storage account.

**Below steps to be followed in-order to implement custom solution using Azure monitor:**

1. Create a log analytics workspace.
2. Enable the [Diagnostic settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?tabs=portal) on the storage account and send these logs to  the above Log analytics workspace.
3. Here is Kusto query to pull the Create Container operations on the storage account:

```html
    StorageBlobLogs
    | where OperationName =~ "CreateContainer" and AccountName =~ '<StorageAccountName>'
    | project  Uri
```

4. click on `New alert rule option` in the log analytics space to create a custom alert using the above query as signal as shown below.

[image]

5. In signal condition, set `Aggregation Granularity` (The interval over which datapoints are grouped by the aggregation type.),`Frequency of evalution`
   (determines how often the alert rule should run) to 5 minutes.
6. Using Actions groups, you send an email or sms notification when the alert criteria has met. You can use the existing action group or you can [create a new action group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups) while configuring the alert.

**Here is the sample image of the alert rule that was created using the above query:**

[image]

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

**Note**:
Here we are using the custom log search as condition signal, if you want know which container got created and this alert got fired click on `Search Results` in your alert notification email.

Comment: Great in depth explanation to my question, which is why I bookmarked it. However, for my query I used the following code which also gives me the container name in the email: AzureActivity |where OperationNameValue contains "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/write"